# Visual Studio 2017 leaves browser open

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In VS2015 and earlier, when you started debugging a web application or site, it opened IE (or edge) or even chrome to view and test your project.   When you closed the browser, the debugger would stop and when you stopped debugging the browser would close.  In VS2017, this behavior does not happen.  I find myself leaving tons of browser windows open all over the place.  I would much prefer if it would simply behave as it did in VS2015 and clean up after itself.

I am sure there is a reason for this but I cannot fathom it.  Is there a way to get this behavior in VS2017?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug/issue this is a **[`feature`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/)** you can disable by inside Debug -> Options you can disable it now.

[image]

Comment: Yea.  I wish.  I tried that before posting but it didn't seem to make any kind of change.  I'll keep futzing with it.  Thanks!